Why does Trump want to raise/cancel the debt ceiling if DOGE will save trillions?
Elon Musk and Vivek Ramaswamy say they can save trillions in government wasteful spending.
If that is so, why would the debt ceiling need to be raised or cancelled?

Voting to close - Please include references to your claims in the question and improve it.

Quite simple, really.
The savings may happen..., later
Economist

Mr Musk has talked of ripping $2trn from the federal budget, an amount that, if done in a year, would exceed the government’s entire discretionary spending. His focus on deregulation, job cuts and fraud is unlikely to provide the requisite savings. Donald Trump has given DOGE less than two years. The entity is an advisory body. And its name is inspired by a joke cryptocurrency.


First, America’s fiscal trajectory is unsustainable. The national debt is approaching 100% of GDP, up from 35% in 2007. With the federal deficit running at 6% of GDP—a level once associated with wars and economic downturns—debts are bound to climb higher still, raising the risk of a crisis.


Whereas cutting $2trn in a year is absurd—it would leave public offices incapable of performing basic functions, and most likely involve slashing the defence budget—achieving those sorts of savings over the course of a decade is eminently doable.

... follows a bunch of sensible, but politically explosive reforms that Trump is highly unlikely to ever consider putting in place, such as upping the retirement age or, gasp, more funding for the IRS to improve tax revenues ...
the deficit will increase right away, before those uncertain savings
CBO May 2024

Extending Trump Tax Cuts Would Add $4.6 Trillion to the Deficit, CBO Finds
Washington, D.C.—According to the latest report by the nonpartisan Congressional Budget Office (CBO), extending the Trump tax cuts for the next 10 years—as Republicans have proposed—would add $4.6 trillion to the deficit.


The report, written at the urging of Senator Whitehouse (D-RI), Chairman of the Senate Budget Committee, and Senator Wyden (D-OR), Chairman of the Senate Finance Committee, finds that the extension would cost $1.1 trillion more than previously estimated.  The Trump tax cuts overwhelmingly benefit large corporations and the wealthiest Americans, and extending them remains a top policy priority among Republicans.

OK, even though the above comes from the government it sounds a bit more partisan than the CBO usually does.  From the horse's mouth (i.e. the CBO itself):

The 2017 Tax Act’s Changes to Individual Income Tax Provisions Are Extended
Most of the individual income tax provisions of the 2017 tax act are slated to expire at the end of calendar year 2025. The expiring provisions affect major elements of the individual income tax code, including the statutory tax rates and brackets, the allowable deductions, the size and refundability of the child tax credit, the 20 percent deduction for certain business income, and the income levels at which the alternative minimum tax takes effect.14


According to JCT’s estimates, if the expiring individual income tax provisions of the 2017 tax act were extended, primary deficits over the 2025–2034 period would be $3.3 trillion larger, on net, than those in CBO’s baseline projections (see Table 2). Most of the effects would occur after 2026. Increased net outlays for interest would add $467 billion to those deficits.

In any case, even assuming charitably that those savings are really believed in by the proponents of those tax cuts, the tax cuts will have to be renewed in 2025, before the savings have been realized.
So the obvious solution, especially to sidestep concerns about increased deficits when trying to renew the tax cuts is to get rid of the debt ceiling.  Mind you, that is not, by itself, a totally stupid idea - the yearly theater around the debt ceiling, with the occasional governmental shutdown, is hardly very productive.  But adding Trump's lets-run-up-the-credit-card-and-call-it-growth approach to economics is hardly reassuring.
p.s. Musk, besides being a bit of a nutjob, can certainly be competent at cost-cutting.  Against that, how often do challenger politicians promise that "waste will be cut" once they are in office? Before finding it very difficult, both operationally and politically to do so?  Musk may fancy himself as Milei, but the US is not in Argentina's situation, US voters have more agency than Twitter employees and Trump will hang Musk out to dry if he either overshadows him or damages his popularity with the base.

p.s.  I am a bit conflicted about this question, which I upvoted.  It does make Trump look foolish, for sure.  That would be a no-no if deliberate and worth closing.  But the stakes are also very, very, high, budget-wise and I am unsure that, given the circumstances, it could have been asked differently, without making Trump look foolish.

Well, this ignores the fact that Trump is only the President, and doesn't get to decide which programs and depts are funded. At best, he can attempt to influence Congress. But given the spending showdown, he has already exposed his weakness in this area.

@LawnmowerMan POTUS have massive influence over the fiscal stance taken during their administration.  From Reagan's "trickle down theory" to Clinton's balancing of the budget, to Trump1's tax cuts. Esp. when they control Congress.  There'll be no one else to blame if the deficit blows up.

You must have been watching some other show. From where I live, it damn sure looks like there is always someone else to blame.

@ItalianPhilosopher I don't understand this statement.  The question doesn't make Trump look foolish.  Trumps statements do that, whether the question is asked or not.  It's like saying "these pants make my butt look big".  No, your big butt makes your butt look big.  The pants aren't the issue.

@ItalianPhilosopher: We don't close neutrally-worded questions just because they make Trump (or anyone) "look foolish." Sometimes we close facially neutral questions because they have no useful answer beyond "yes, that is indeed what happened," but that answer does not apply to this question.

Trump has repeatedly said that he intends to extend his 2017 tax cuts (primarily for the ultra-rich and big corporations), which are scheduled to expire next year. And according to TaxFoundation.org, when we add in other aspects of his tax and tariff proposals during the campaign, this will significantly increase US debt.
Removing the debt ceiling will make it much easier for him to implement his plans.

I realize it's all B.S., propaganda, and outright lies, but are Trump's tax cuts for the ultra-rich oligarchs greater than the trillions that Musk/Ramaswamy claimed they will magically reduce in spending?

@AmazonDiesInDarkness I don't know what the expected savings are from DOGE. I think it's all very fuzzy at the moment. It will likely take quite a bit of time to implement DOGE's changes (most require Congressional legislation) while Trump will try to extend the tax cuts immediately.

That's a good point about the timing. Even though there is good reason to not believe a word coming out of Musk or Ramaswamy's mouth(s), they make it sound like what they claim they will do will be instantaneous.  The reality, as you point out, is that if they do anything, it will take time. Thanks for clarifying that important point.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness As another example, consider how many things Trump says he plans on doing on day 1. Maybe the first thing he needs to do is add hours to the day. :)

Given that he reportedly doesn't get anything done before 11am, and often takes at least one long nap, he's going to have to add more days to the day. ;)

To quote Trump (slightly out of context) in relation to the debt ceiling:

And, by the way, you’re going to default eventually, anyway, but it’s going to be much messier. I don’t think you’ll have to default. I think, if the Republicans hold strong and they say “We want five” – let’s say, “We want $5 trillion off,” I really think the Democrats have no choice but to do it. And if I win, they’re going to be doing the same thing to me in two years, I guarantee you that. They’re going to play a very hardball game…

To quote him earlier in that same interview:

COLLINS: You once said that using the – that using the debt ceiling as a negotiating wedge just could not happen. You – you said that when you were in the Oval Office.
TRUMP: Sure, that’s when I was president.
COLLINS: So why is it different now that you’re out of office?
TRUMP: Because now I’m not president.

Bill Clinton seems to have been the last president who actually cared about the spiraling national debt. His successors either didn't care or came to the conclusion that the national debt is growing so rapidly that in the end the government is one day going to default anyway. Therefore you may as well as do whatever makes you popular and hope that the default does not happen while you are president. Trump finds himself in the following situation. On the one hand, he needs support from fiscal conservatives who want the national debt cut. On the other hand, he can not infuriate those who would be adversely affected were the government to start acting with fiscal restraint. His solution to be everything to everyone is to claim to be cutting government wasteful spending, while keeping up the policies that will cause the deficit to grow, even if wasteful spending is cut.
Being that he knows that, at the end of the day, the deficit will grow during the second term and the Democrats will give him a hard time about raising the debt ceiling, he wants it done away with. As he very straight out said in the interview, he knows that what he is doing may be wrong but that is the type of thing you only say when you are in opposition.

The interest on the US National Debt should also be considered. It is one of the largest budget items.
Even if spending was cut dramatically, the interest on the 36T debt will need to be served while the debt is paid down.

This has been an ongoing concern, including during his first term. But I don't remember him calling for removal of the debt ceiling then.

Interest rates were much lower then, among a lot of other considerations.

@DogBoy37 Are current interest rates significantly relevant? (if that's too big a question for a comment, I can break it out into a separate QA, likely for the Economics SE).

@Barmar I imagine he probably learned his lesson from back then. He already has a very small house majority, and especially if he's making unpopular cuts (which he'll be forced to do if he wants to seriously reduce spending) it's quite likely the Democrats will control the house again in the second part of his presidency. At which point the debt ceiling would be a very useful weapon for them to force the president to alter policies. Which IIRC they did during his first tenure as well. Cutting the ceiling while he still has a majority would save him a lot of potential pain later.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness  "Significantly" is a loaded word.  For example: April12th, 2021 the T Bill rate was 0.06%.  Dec 9th, 2024 it is 4.24%. IMHO that is significant, but I am a business owner not a professional or self-professed expert in economics. Yes - there is more involved than just the T Bill rate, but we're not talking about nuanced affects.

@DogBoy37 Yes, as an individual business owner, that T-Bill rate difference is likely significant to you.  What I'm uncertain about is how much it matters for existing government debt payments.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness it is an indicator of the rate the government is paying for on the debt. It is a variable rate loan not much different (other than the best rate there is) than any other loan. Keep in mind, they have only been servicing interest, no paying down principal in for years. So, if not directly T-Bill rate, it shows what is being paid on the interest.

Thank you. The first two sentences you wrote answered exactly what I wanted to better understand.

Because of entitlements spending
Here's a simplified diagram of the 2023 outlays and revenue in the American budget. "Mandatory" spending here refers to Social Security, Medicare, Medicaid and various other welfare programs:

The total deficit is $6.1T - $4.4% = $1.7T, meaning DOGE would have to cut down 100% of all non-entitlement spending just to break even - and even Musk would probably admit cutting down government by 100% is impossible. You could also optimize things on the margin in the distribution of entitlements, but at the end of the day there's only three solutions:

Reduce entitlements and/or raise the age of retirement => extremely unpopular.
Large and persistent inflation => extremely unpopular.
"Kick the can down the road" => not super popular but currently the most palatable option to most voters. And Musk's plans (if implemented) would be quite helpful in at least helping the country hold out on cuts till the next Presidential election. Trump will be ineligible for office at that point, so after that... Après moi, le déluge.


The reason why mandatory spending is shooting up is because baby boomers are retiring, drawing social security and needing medical care. Once they age out, relative spending is going back down. This is the other half of the roller coaster we saw 1980-2010 when social security was running at a surplus, so doing nothing is not a dumb option: we smooth out the hump by borrowing, and not make drastic changes for something, which as far as we can see, will not happen again.

@user71659 It's not necessarily a smart option either. That huge mandatory spending is here to stay for a decade or more and that social security surplus is likely not coming back afterwards to pay all the debt down. So in the end, the result of doing nothing can very well be lots and lots of debt and yet still running a deficit afterwards.

@user71659 there's another factor having a significant influence: people live longer. While it took a big drop in the US these last years, the overall trend is clearly upwards. And yet another issue is that there are less people of working age to pay for all that, so even if the cost goes down, the associated revenue may not match up.

@TooTea Social Security is a PAYGO system. What this means is we have a social contract to support our parents in retirement. Either you break the contract (point 1), or you tough it out.

@user71659 Yes, it's baby boomers retiring (and people living longer), but the problem is actually the inverse of what you said: 2 parents retiring and consuming social security with only 1 child working and paying into social security is the problem. Not 2 parents retiring who had 3 children paying taxes. The problem will get worse, not better, because our birth rate continues to go down, so fewer workers pay into taxes, more retirees consume them. Japan demonstrates this clearly, having extreme old age population with few births.

@JaminGrey What you need to do is actually save money while you're working and rely on your own savings when you retire. As I noted, Social Security is a PAYGO system where the young directly support the old, and the same pyramid scheme happens in most corporate and public employee pensions. (Prime example: USPS screaming about prefunding their pensions.) The solution is the 401(k) the majority of Americans are on. The other patch is immigration, which Western European countries are pursuing, and your example of Japan is a society notoriously closed to immigration.

@jcaron Americans are about to get a huge boost in life expectancy thanks to GLP-1 drugs. If every obese person lost the extra weight, that'd easily add 5 years to a persons expected survival years at age 65

First, Trump would like to eliminate the debt ceiling, not just raise it.
Secondly, the debt ceiling is a political hot-potato, political theater masquerading as economic policy.  CR’s are no way run a democracy.
The debt ceiling which is raised by a continuing resolution has nothing to do with saving money by eliminating government inefficiencies (except it is an example of a government inefficiency), it also does nothing to actually reduce spending.
In short the only thing the two have in common is money, and everything is connected to money

The idea was that he could cut taxes without worrying about that creating deficits.

This is a comment rather than a full-fledged answer.

It seems a reasonable answer to me.  we have claims from several sources that tend to lie more often than not. There's not much point in examining those claims in detail,  and this motive seems a reasonable explanation for making those claims.
